# ARIMA(1,1,1) Model - Forecast

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

How does one

1. write the mathematical equation for the ARIMA(1,1,1) model with the estimated coefficients below and
2. use the ARIMA(1,1,1) model and time series points below to produce a forecast value for time = 41 (e.g. the forecast value for t = 41 is 18)?

   > auto.arima(deseasonal_cnt, seasonal=FALSE)
   >
   > Series: deseasonal_cnt
   >   ARIMA(1,1,1)
   >
   > Coefficients:
   >
   > ```
   >   ar1     ma1
   >   0.5510  -0.2496
   > ```
   >
   > s.e.  0.0751   0.0849
   >
   > sigma^2 estimated as 26180:  log likelihood=-4708.91  
   >   AIC=9423.82   AICc=9423.85   BIC=9437.57
   >
   > airplane[35:40]
   >   19.2981  17.1230  16.1230  18.1352  19.3401  18.1414
   >
   > fitted(Arima(airplane, c(1,1,1)))[35:40]
   >   18.3492  18.3752  17.8322  18.7924  19.8253  18.8198

Comment: Check out similar questions on this site and you will find a dozen answers.

Answer (score 0):

All ARIMA models can be expressed in a similar form to this [image]

Comment: What do your variables $Y$, $X$, $a$ refer to?  They don't seem to connect with anything named in the question, so some explanation is needed.

Comment: Y is the observed dependent series (endogenous) and the X's are possible exogenous series either user-specified or analytically developed (pulses/level shiftts/trends.seasonal pulses)... none in this case.